# Cant have div fill other div except for border

Tags: css

Hey so I'm trying to create a nested div element so that it lies within another div element but fills up its parent entirely except for a perfect border around it that 30 px or so like this http://s23.postimg.org/su2o83m7v/div.png

I've tried padding, margins and positioning with css but cant seem to keep its width and the bottom part of the padding, any suggestions?

Comment: share your code......

Comment: Would like to see some html and css here, better make a fiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/62Mjt/ I dont know if its my internet making it not show up or if I made a syntax error for just the fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways to go about this.

1) Box-sizing

```
.OuterDiv {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    border:30px solid green;
}

.InnerDiv {
    background-color:red;
    border:4px solid blue;
}
```

[Here is the jsFiddle for it.](http://jsfiddle.net/uuPR2/2/)

2) Position absolute

```
.OuterDiv {
    position:relative;
    height:100px;
    background-color:green;
}

.InnerDiv {
    position:absolute;
    top:30px;
    left:30px;
    right:30px;
    bottom:30px;
    background-color:red;
    border:4px solid blue;
}
```

[Here is the jsFiddle for that.](http://jsfiddle.net/uuPR2/3/)

Personally I would choose the first option any day of the week (hell of a lot easier to maintain, and really you should use `box-sizing:border-box;` for everything), but if you desperately need IE7 support the second one will work there whereas the first is only IE8+.

Comment: thanks, but the reason I wanted a div border is so that I can have a border around the "border", anyway to do that?

Comment: you mean have a border around the inner box? by default the borders will surround the border of that inner box, i've updated my answer and jsFiddle to show what I mean.

Comment: outer, but I guess that would work too, I'm looking into `display:inline-block` and if that doesn't work ill use your solution. thanks!

Comment: no worries, but `display:inline-block` is used for aligning siblings, not nesting children. i highly advocate it over floats, but i'm not sure it would help much here. either way, glad i could be of assistance!

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code

```
    <html>
     <head>
      <style>
        .outer{
         height:200px;
         width:200px;
         padding:30px;
         background-color:#ff0000;
        }
        .inner{
          height:100%;
          width:100%;
          background-color:#00FF00;
        }
      </style>
     </head>
     <body> 
       <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner">
        </div>
       </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

I am giving the outer div padding of 30px, and rest is simple just made height & width 100%
 used background-color to show the div differently

Answer (score 0):

I found this too work as well

```
#parent
{
    border:1px solid black;
    background:#ddd;
    display:inline-block;
}

#child
{
    width:180px;
    margin:30px;
    background:grey;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Y37su/